# Чтение файла из другого ПК по локальной сети

Tags: c#

Есть такой вот путь

```
string[] text = File.ReadAllLines(@"//127.0.0.1/Users/strong/Desktop/MyProject/WpfAfppli/WpfApplication/Testy/MyFiles/MyFiles.txt");
MessageBox.Show(text[0]);
```

Но он работает только если проект на диске С. Как сделать так что бы работало на любых дисках. Нужно что бы по IP было, так как это путь к проекту на сервере .
За ранее спасибо за любую помощь

Comment: Скачивайте файл на комп и читайте

Comment: Вопрос в том, каким образом сервер раздаёт файлы.

Comment: так он не раздает, они лежат в папке  сервером, затем по этой ссылке я получаю к нему доступ. После IP указывается каталог в котором находится сервер, вместо Users может быть С или D . Как вообще определить в каком из каталогов запущен сервер ? сервер это программа, чат

Comment: Нет, так это не работает. В адресе указывается путь относительно базовой расшареной папки и ни как иначе. Формат адреса: `//<server>[:<port>]/<shareName>[/<subfolder>]*`. В `[ ]` указаны не обязательные элементы. А для чего вам это?

Comment: У меня клиент-серверное приложение, и мне нужно с клиента(второй ПК), прочитать файл на сервере(первый ПК). И мой путь который я указал работает, но проблема в том что я не могу узнать сетевое имя диска, что мы программа могла бы проложить путь дальше. Обычно сетевое имя по дефолту это d, или если это диск "C" то с. Мне всего лишь нужно узнать сетевое имя диска на котором запущено приложение(сервер). Затем я просто укажу его после IP адресса, и все заработает. Но вот как узнать это имя ? я не знаю, у меня еть пример кода, но  он выводит еще и другие какие то имена.

Comment: А что это за код и какие "другие" имена он выводит нужно догадаться самим? Добавьте этот код и его вывод в вопрос. Для этого под вопросом есть кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/673490/edit)